# Aligning gif center in app-root to center in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

How do you align gif spinner enclosed between  to center. I tried using CSS however it still stays at top-right(default) position. No matter what. I want it to appear in center of the screen

```
<app-root>
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loading-img"><img src="./assets/images/loading.gif"></div>
    <h1 style="right: 10px">Loading...</h1>
  </div>
</app-root>

.loading
{
 margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Basically use absolute positioning to align your image with the center point of your screen. Then offset the image up and to the left using top and left css properties.

```css
html { 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%; 
}

img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 500px;
   height: 250px;
   margin-top: -175px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
 <img src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/023/397/C-658VsXoAo3ovC.jpg" />
</div>
```

In your case you are not using an image but the concept still applies. You can make your loading div absolute and position it wherever you want on your app.

As per the angular - I think you are on the right track about putting your spinner in the AppComponent. That would seem like a great spot to put it.

You can also subscribe to the router events and have your spinner start if your app starts to navigate to a new page.

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
   this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart)
          // turn on spinner
      else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd)
         // turn off spinner
   });
}
```